# Javascript code dont exec : IsFormValid()

Tags: javascript, php, validation

i got a form in another .php file that I include in my main file index.php; the problem is that the Form wont run my javascript isValidForm(). I tried with OnClick and OnSubmit, even tried the two togeher to force it. But the form just do the action, and dont exec the Javascript code.

```
 <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function isValidForm(){
                          var string1 = document.getElementById('captcha1').value);
                          var string2 = document.getElementById('captcha2').value);
                          if (string1==string2){
                            return true;
                          }
                          else{        
                            return false;
                          }
                      }
        </script>


    <div class="top-menu">
     <?php include 'menu_top.php';?>
    </div>
```

and them i got the form in the file i included "menu_top.php" index:

```
 <form id="form_login" action="actions/login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return isValidForm();">               
       <input name="Captcha" id="captcha1" type="text" style="width:200px !important;" class="input_text" placeholder="captcha code"/>
       <input type="submit" value="login" class="button" onClick="return isValidForm();">
    </form>
```

Comment: The code looks fine, can you provide a working example as code snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Check my answer hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a syntax error in below two lines.

```
var string1 = document.getElementById('captcha1').value;
var string2 = document.getElementById('captcha2').value;
```

Also change in form:

```
<form id="form_login" action="actions/login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return isValidForm();"> 
<input name="Captcha" id="captcha1" type="text" style="width:200px !important;" class="input_text" placeholder="captcha code"/>
<input name="Captcha" id="captcha2" type="text" style="width:200px !important;" class="input_text" placeholder="captcha code"/>
<input type="submit" value="login" class="button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see Two issues in this

1) you have added extra closing bracket where you r trying to get the value.

2) Please check are you getting "captcha2" value?

script

```
 function isValidForm(){
                      var string1 = document.getElementById('captcha1').value;
                      var string2 = document.getElementById('captcha2').value;
                      if (string1==string2){
                        return true;
                      }
                      else{        
                        return false;
                      }
                  }
```

html

```
<form id="form_login" action="actions/login.php" method="post" onsubmit="return isValidForm()">               
   <input name="Captcha" id="captcha1" type="text" style="width:200px !important;" class="input_text" placeholder="captcha code"/>
    <input name="Captcha" id="captcha2" type="text" style="width:200px !important;" class="input_text" placeholder="captcha code"/>
   <input type="submit" value="login" class="button">
</form>
```

[codepen working example](https://codepen.io/naseer/pen/GmMxrY)